# Got Stuck When Installing Octave in High Sierra

Tags: command-line, high-sierra, install, homebrew, open-source

I've tried to install Octave using homebrew by using this command:
`brew install octave`.
But after `make` sign, I got stuck and nothing happened more than a half hour.

```
➜  ~ brew install octave
==> Installing dependencies for octave: gcc, veclibfort, arpack, jpeg, libtiff, little-cms2, ghostscript, epstool, fftw, cmake, jasper, netpbm, fig2dev, fltk, freetype, fontconfig, gl2ps, glpk, webp, gd, lua, gnuplot, graphicsmagick, szip, hdf5, flac, libogg, libvorbis, libsndfile, pcre, portaudio, plotutils, xz, imagemagick, pstoedit, qhull, qrupdate, metis, suite-sparse
==> Installing octave dependency: gcc
==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-8.1.0/gcc-8
Already downloaded: /Users/asrulsibaoel/Library/Caches/Homebrew/gcc-8.1.0.tar.xz
==> ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0 --prefix
==> make
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The installation appears to be waiting on installing `gcc`. Take the following measures one by one.

1. If the installation is still stuck at `make`, cancel it by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>.
2. Enter `brew cleanup --prune=0` to clear the local cache.
3. Enter `brew update` followed by `brew upgrade` to update the local cache of package repository.
4. Run `brew config` and check the output corresponding to `CLT:` key. It should shaw the version of installed Command Line Tools. If it says `NA`, install Command Line Tools by executing `xcode-select --install`.
5. Once Command Line Tools are done installing, confirm by observing the output of `brew config`.
6. Reattempt installation of Octave by running `brew install octave`.

Answer (score 1):

I found [Octave.app](http://octave-app.org/) when searching for resolution to problems related to the homebrew installation of `octave` on High Sierra.

The Octave.app has at macOS based testing suite. And when needed, has even applied patches to address [upstream code issues](https://github.com/octave-app/octave-app-bundler/issues/13).

*`Octave.app` is based on the homebrew build, just with the value add of macOS specific testing, bundling, … and patching.*

Indeed, Octave.app even had fixed the very Qt issue(s?) that appeared to be causing problems with the homebrew release in my case. Since Octave.app patched the upstream Qt issues which Homebrew had not, I unlinked the homebrew version and installed Octave.app.

```
# if octave exists from either regular Homebrew or dpo/openblas formulae 
brew unlink octave
```

[Octave.app](http://octave-app.org/) launches OK in GUI mode. [Octave.app installs from a dmg](http://octave-app.org/Download.html). Thus, neither `Homebrew` nor `MacPorts` are required.

I also added the following to the bash profile:

```
##############
### Octave ###
##############
### http://octave-app.org/
alias octave="open -a \"Octave\""
```